# how to insert row from tableview with animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I am new to iphone please help to me, in my app display data on tableview access from sql server through web services but my problem is when insert new row and add to tableview newly entered row is added to tableview but it add normally, I want to add animation while adding new row to tableview. I don't know how to add animation to tableview after enter new record, anyone have any idea please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

To insert a row:

```
    int rowIndex = 0;//your row index where you want to add cell
    int sectionIndex = 0;//your section index
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:iPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

But you need to make sure, that you have a additional record, at specified index in your `dataSourse` Array(the array you are using to populate data in your table).

Answer (score 1):

> insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
>
> Inserts rows in the receiver at the
>   locations identified by an array of
>   index paths, with an option to animate
>   the insertion.

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)

Comment: thank you but i don't have an idea how to use this method can u please sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` of UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** So if you insert the data on top of tableview, then the user has to scroll down to find where he left?

**Solution:** why not make that scroll down for the user by calculating an offset and setting the offset before the tableview updates finish.

How to calculate that offset?
(number of cells inserting on top) * (the cells height)

**Note**: on the below example/calculation I subtract two cells from the number of cells I am inserting to give the user a peek preview that theres data on top

```
    [strongSelf.tableView beginUpdates];

    //INSERT DATA & CELLS ON TOP

    //REMOVE DATA ON BOTTOM IF NECESSARY

    //moving scrollview right back down so user can resume where last left off
    NSInteger estimatedRow = strongSelf.tableView.rowHeight * ( (indexPathsAdding.count) - 2);
    [strongSelf.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, estimatedRow)];


    [strongSelf.tableView endUpdates];
```